# Magento 2: Overriding email CSS in custom theme

Tags: magento2, css, order-email, custom-theme

I have created my own custom theme. When customer places an order, order email does not load css correctly. I directly changed in core css files of luma and blank theme but it seems like fall back is not working as magento is not showing my changes even after updating core files.

Any idea why its not loading css or is there any way override email css in my custom theme so that css should be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the following files in your theme to do most of the order-mail styling:

```
Magento_Sales/web/css/source/_email.less
```

and

```
Magento_Sales/web/css/source/_module.less
```

After making changes to these files, you'll have to do a `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` To make the changes visible.

Comment: Where to get those two files? I didn't find files in vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/web

Comment: I took them from theme-frontend-blank.

vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Sales/web/css/source/_email.less

Comment: I placed those files and added my own style in it but it didn't work.

Comment: Hmm, currently I don't have time to try it myself, but have you tried:
rm -Rf pub/static/* var/view_preprocessed/*
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
bin/magento cache:clean

Comment: @umairayub , did you find the solution?

Comment: @Koen, the same issue i am facing.Can you please let me know the proper solution.Thanks!